# Спецсимвол стрелка Excel/Javascript

Tags: массивы, символы, javascript, excel, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте.

Есть табличка в Excel, 9 х 9, со значениями. Копирую в буфер обмена, вставляю в Notepad++, включаю отображение спецсимволов и вижу, что в качестве пробела используется точка посередине строки, а в качестве разделителя колонок - стрелка (иногда короткая, иногда длинная).

Как-то так:

```
Var1•var→Var12---→Var3
Var1→Var12-→Var3•var
Var1→Var12→Var3•var
```

Только точки и стрелки там по-другому выглядят.

Как указать эти спецсимволы в качестве разделителя для массива?

```
arr = "Var1•var→Var12---→Var3".split('вот тут нужно указать эту стрелку');
```

Например, так можно разбить на строки:

```
arr = d.split('\n');
```

где "d" - это переменная, в которой хранятся данные, взятые из Excel.

Посмотрел коды специальных символов в таблице, но таких там нет.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотреть код символа в таблице символов (например, в Win такая есть где-то в Пуске или в инете поищи) и указать этот код. Это если программно разбить надо. Если руками, то можно ввести его через Alt+Numpad_Code.

Хотя погоди. Ты же включаешь отображение спецсимволов. Вот они у тебя и отображаются точками и стрелочками. В программе задавай просто пробел и \n\r или просто EOL (end of line) в php.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

А автозамена не подходит? Notepad`е есть такая функция...